# Setting up postgres ts_vector column

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, tsvector

I have a search table in postgres with a ts_vector column. It looks like when I insert a dstring to this column is vectorizes it, but it doesn't do any stemming or removal of stop words:

```
test=# create table sample_ts_vec ( id varchar(255), tsv tsvector);
CREATE TABLE
test=# insert into sample_ts_vec values ('t1234', 'this is a test');
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from sample_ts_vec;
  id   |          tsv           
-------+------------------------
 t1234 | 'a' 'is' 'test' 'this'
(1 row)

test=# insert into sample_ts_vec values ('t1235', to_tsvector('this is a test'));
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from sample_ts_vec;
  id   |          tsv           
-------+------------------------
 t1234 | 'a' 'is' 'test' 'this'
 t1235 | 'test':4
(2 rows)
```

You'll notice that in the second insert, the 3 stop words are removed, and the word is stemmed (in this case, no stemming necessary), whereas in the first example each word gets added. How can I apply the to_tsvector function automagically to the string value prior to insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasen's answer was close, but it had a few important errors - here's the corrected version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tsvfix() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.tsv=to_tsvector(NEW.tsv);
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER "tsvfix" BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON "sample_ts_vec" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvfix();
```

Even this doesn't work however. I get an error `ERROR: function to_tsvector(tsvector) does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

you could create a `TRIGGER` for `ON UPDATE OR INSERT` 
assuming the table has a column data which you want to make a tsv index on, something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION tsvfix() RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW.tsv=to_tsvector(NEW.data);
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$;

CREATE TRIGER "tsvfix" ON UPDATE OR INSERT TO "sample_ts_vec" EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvfix;
```

Comment: thanks I think this is heading in the right direction. I'm getting an error `ERROR:  function to_tsvector(tsvector) does not exist`, so I think the string value has already been converted to ts_vector by this point?

Comment: I think the last line should read `CREATE TRIGGER "tsvfix" BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON "sample_ts_vec" EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvfix();` and also, I think `to_tsvector(NEW.data)` should be `to_tsvector(NEW.tsv)`?